# Gravity PDF & Gravity Perks Nested Field

Tags: pdf, nested, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm using Gravity PDF and have a Nested field from Gravity Perks.  I can view fields in the normal exploded results just fine, but am having trouble when I want to display the Nested field in a particular location using the PHP option.

To be clear, I can get the normal $form_data['field'] and $form_data['list'] options to work just fine.  But when I try to get one of those to fire a Gravity Form Nested Field I have issues.  I've used a lot of combinations...

```html
<?php echo $form_data['field'][27.72]; ?>
<?php echo $form_data['gpnf'][27]['gpnf']; ?>
<?php echo $form_data['field'][27]['gpnf']; ?>
<?php echo $form_data['field']['gpnf_display_value_27_72']; ?>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  Got it working earlier today and been fiddling with it all day.  Just had to setup an API.  First you use the original $form_data to get the Entry_ID
 $client = $form_data['field'][32];

Then you point the API to the form_id you want:
 $form_id2 = '27';
 $entry2 = GFAPI::get_entry( $client );

And then it was a really easy variant of the rgar:

You need to setup $form_id2 and $entry2 or something like that because if you don't it changes the other ones in the PDF that are pointed at the original Form.

From here I've been able to customize the heck out of it.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know the answer, but I use gravity forms and perks, and the perks support is really good and usually get back quickly with a response. Might try emailing them if you haven't already.

Comment: Yeah, but they are out til Monday. Thanks though.